# Vue.js + Element-ui Upload: how call method ClearFiles or Abort

Tags: javascript, upload, vuejs2, element-ui

I'm using `vue.js` and `element-ui`.

I'd like to use the `upload-file` component to send files to my server.

I want to stop loading a file to the server, if such file already exists. I want to use the claimed method `abort` or `clearFiles`, but can't.
What's my mistake?

**HTML**

```
<el-upload
     action="",
     :http-request="addAttachment",
     :on-remove="deleteAttachment",
     :before-upload="handleBeforeUpload",
     :file-list="fileList">
</el-upload>
<el-button size="small" type="success" @click="clearFiles">clear</el-button>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    data() {
        return {
            fileList: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        handleBeforeUpload(file) {
            //if loading file exists in fileList - abort 
            if (findIndexInFileList(file) >= 0) {
                clearFiles(); //error
                this.clearFiles(); //.. and error
                vm.clearFiles(); //.. and also error
            }
        }
    }
}).$mount('#app');

vm.clearFiles(); //error!
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @franiis, "vue.js:6 ReferenceError: clearFiles is not defined"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With refs!
add ref attribute to el-upload

```
<el-upload
 ref="upload">
</el-upload>
```

Then call via $refs object

```
this.$refs.upload.clearFiles()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what about abort() ? It's not work, fileList not updated.

Comment: in case someone finds this 1 year later like me: fileList just holds the default values NOT the files you upload. clearFiles()  seems to just clean up the UI